# Adding Hyperlink to text inside Boxable Cell - PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox, boxable

Hope all are good. I am relatively new to Boxable and PDFBox and was hoping someone could help me in this regard. I am trying to generate a PDF using PDFBox and since I was required to create tables which I did, now I need to put a hyperlink text in it. I am trying but unable to find any help on this. I know PDFBox has a way of doing it using 'PDAnnotationLink' but that is not working when I'm trying to insert it into a Boxable Cell since that requires only String values.

Bit of my code is something like this,

```
Row<PDPage> row = table.createRow(rowHeight);
Cell<PDPage> cell = otherDocumentsRow.createCell(30, "Other Documents");
String str = "Attachment link here";
cell = row.createCell(70, str);
```

Now instead of str text, I am looking to insert a hyperlink text which points to some location (www.example.com). Is this possible or is there a workaround around this.

Thank you in advance and looking forward to hearing from you

Comment: what does createCell accept as parameters?

Comment: createCell(float width, String text)

Comment: since a flat string is not an url .. no. but what is stopping you from extending it?

Comment: @Stultuske What do you mean extending it? Can you please elaborate! All I need is to display a hyperlink inside cell ... any advice or workaround will be greatly appreciated

Comment: as in inheritance? if you don't know that, stop what you're doing and learn the basics first

Comment: @Stultuske - I know inheritance, not really sure how to use it in this context, didn't think about using here but I'll see and will update

Comment: you can extend Cell and add a method that allows to add an url